# Is there a way to tell maven where to place the artifacts?

Tags: java, maven-2, cygwin

I am running both maven inside the m2eclipse plugin, windows command line and my cygwin command line.

cygwin's bash shell dumps artifacts into the cygwin /home/me/.m2 directory

but m2eclipse & windows shell (on vista) uses /Users/me/Documents/.m2

Is it possible to tell the mvn command to use one central .m2 directory ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Cygwin, create a file called ~/.mavenrc and put the following text inside:

```
MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.repo.local=c:\documents and settings\user\.m2\repository"
export MAVEN_OPTS
```

Alternatively, you can create the file under /etc/.mavenrc

Another option is to create [NTFS junction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx) between .m2 under your windows and your cygwin profile.

Comment: MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.repo.local=c:\documents and settings\user\.m2\repository"  **repository** in path should be included.

Answer (score 17):

Sure, several ways.  The most typical is to specify this in your settings.xml file:

- http://maven.apache.org/settings.html

> ```
> <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
>   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
>                       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
>   <localRepository>/my/secret/repository</localRepository>
> </settings>
> ```