# Maven local repository setting being overridden

Tags: maven

My local maven build has been failing due to plugin dependencies not resolving. I've found on SO that this is likely caused by the correct settings not being picked up. So I ran `mvn clean install -X` to check which settings files are being used. The relevant part of the output from debug is:

```
[DEBUG] Reading global settings from c:\Maven\apache-maven-3.2.5\conf\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Reading user settings from h:\.m2\settings.xml
[DEBUG] Using local repository at C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.2.5\repo
```

The local repository is defined in both the global and local settings.xml as:

```
<localRepository>C:\.m2\repository\</localRepository>
```

I've been able to build successfully by overriding the local repository via the command line:

```
 mvn clean install -Dmaven.repo.local=my/local/repo
```

My `M2_HOME` environment variable is `C:\Maven\apache-maven-3.2.5`

The command line fix is fine as a workaround but it's not ideal. The local repository is not being defined in the pom.xml.

Other than the settings file, is there anywhere else that the local repository can be defined, and is therefore overriding the configuration in settings.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three (and a half) ways how you can configure your local repo:

1. Globally in `<MAVEN_HOME>/conf/settings.xml`
2. per User in `<USER_HOME>/.m2/settings.xml`
3. per command line arg: `mvn clean install -Dmaven.repo.local=my/local/repo`
4. per environment Variable MAVEN_OPTS: You can set your MAVEN_OPTS to set the maven.repo.local variable for maven operations. It's kind of like passing the environment variable directly, but for all `mvn` calls. See [Is there a way to tell maven where to place the artifacts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207498/is-there-a-way-to-tell-maven-where-to-place-the-artifacts)

The `MAVEN_OPTS`way should be what you're looking for.